# how to arrange two tables on top of each other occupying same width

Tags: html, css

I want to know how to arrange two tables on top of each other and occupying the same width.

Here is the example html:

```
<div class="wd100 gridcntnr">
<table class="wd100 bgred">
    <tbody>
        <tr>
            <td>LOREM IPSUM</td>
            <td>NAME</td>
            <td>ABC</td>
        </tr>
    </tbody>
</table>
<table class="wd100">
    <thead>
        <tr>
        <th>Header 1</th>
        <th>Header 2</th>
        <th>Header 3</th>
        <th>Header 4</th>
        <th>Header 5</th>
        <th>Header 6</th>
        <th>Header 7</th>
        <th>Header 8</th>
        <th>Header 9</th>
        <th>Header 10</th>
        <th>Header 1</th>
        <th>Header 2</th>
        <th>Header 3</th>
        <th>Header 4</th>
        <th>Header 5</th>
        <th>Header 6</th>
        <th>Header 7</th>
        <th>Header 8</th>
        <th>Header 9</th>
        <th>Header 10</th>
        <th>Header 1</th>
        <th>Header 2</th>
        <th>Header 3</th>
        <th>Header 4</th>
        <th>Header 5</th>
        <th>Header 6</th>
        <th>Header 7</th>
        <th>Header 8</th>
        <th>Header 9</th>
        <th>Header 10</th>
        </tr>

    </thead>
    <tbody>
    </tbody>
</table>
  </div>
```

The corresponding css is:

```
.gridcntnr{
overflow:auto;
border: 1px solid black;
}
.wd100{
    width: 100%;
}
.bgred{
    background-color:red;
}
```

I would like to know why there is difference in arrangement of both the tables(extra space is appearing in the top table on the right hand side)and also how to arrange two tables on top of each other and occupying the same width.

I tried using table-layout:fixed; but doing so the second table is getting conjusted and extra space which is appearing in the top table on the right hand side is not removed completely.

Any Help would be appreciated. Please Contribute.

Comment: Question is not clear , can u draw a mspaint diagram or explain in genric ?

Answer (score 0):

Have you tried absolute positioning as per the following document? -> http://www.htmldog.com/guides/css/intermediate/layout/

Answer (score 0):

You can place one table over the top of another through a number of means.  For instance, you could apply a negative margin to the second table like so:

```
.gridcntnr>table:last-child {
    margin-top: -25px;
}
```

Regarding the extra space to the right of the first table, a table will consume as much space as its contents require.  You have far more cells in a row in the second table than the row in the first table.  The first table takes on the 100% width you've defined, but that width is relative to its parent element, the `div`.  The second table overflows the entire width of its parent, requiring you to scroll.  The only way around this is to use a monitor that could fit all of the contents of the second table on the page without scrolling.  Then there would be no extra space to the right of the first table.

But why are you using tables in this way?  You could probably find an easier time using semantic markup.  If displaying data, break up the tables to display the content more easily and in a less-overwhelming way.

Answer (score 0):

You need to have the parent container with a position:relative; and the children with a position:absolute; like so:

```
.gridcntnr {
     position:relative;
     overflow:auto;
     border: 1px solid black;
}
.gridcntnr .wd100 {
     position:absolute;
     width: 100%;
}
.gridcntnr .bgred {
     position:absolute;
     background-color:red;
}
```

Answer (score 0):

You may achieve the requested result by setting the `display` css property of the surrounding div to `table` or `inline-table`

```
.gridcntnr{
    display:inline-table;
    overflow:auto;
    border: 1px solid black;
}
```

Comment: I need the scrollbar to appear at the bottom of the table.